# Updating BootStrapContext with new SessionSecurityToken when using Sliding sessions in WIF with the SAM and Thinktecture IdentityModel

Tags: security, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model

When using sliding sessions in WIF with the session authentication module (SAM) and Thinktecture IdentityModel as described in [brockallen's blog](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/17/sliding-sessions-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/).
The session security token issued and written to the cookie has it's "valid to" extended as required and the cookie is set accordingly.

But, the BootStrapToken serialized to the current claims Identity remains the old one, with the potentially expired token. This causes problems when trying to use the bootstrap context token for different reasons (among them could be [Implementing “Poor Man”’s Delegation](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas/)) .

What is the best way to update the bootstrap token with the new issued token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get a fresh "bootstrap" token is to do a roundtrip to the actual issuer.

Comment: Does this prevents me from using the sliding expiration feature? Or is there a way around this?

Comment: Well - that means that only the issuer can issue the token. You cannot renew it yourself. So if you need a fresh token - do a roundtrip to the issuer.

Comment: And how do I 'roundtrip' to actual issuers? Perhaps something less intrusive and unknown to users (without redirecting users to login page).

Comment: No - you have to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Microsoft's Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS), then you can adjust/increase the timeout of the AD FS relying party token to be longer, which will extend the lifetime of the WIF bootstrap token.

For example, we had an issue where we were getting new session tokens, but we still had timeouts before the AD FS Web SSO timeout.  One of the developers discovered that there is a setting to extend the relying party token's lifetime, which correlates to the bootstrap token in Windows Identity Foundation (WIF).

The setting is below:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName YourTargetName -TokenLifetime 480
```

After we set the relying party token's timeout to be the same as the Web SSO token timeout, then it worked.

Note: You can check the current relying party token's timeout with the following command:

```
Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name YourTargetName
```

Note II: You can check the Web SSO token's timeout by opening the AD FS Management tool, clicking "AD FS" in the left navigation pane, then click "Edit Federation Service Properties..." in the Actions pane in the right pane.