# Thinktecture Identity v2 rolling session security token

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I am currently using Identity for a login system but the session token it creates offers a fixed expiry date of 10 hours. he spec for my system requires the session to expire if the user is idle for 20 minutes. I um unable to find anywhere in the source code to offer a rolling session state.

I have googled the issue and the only solution is to create a new session from the sessionAuthenticationModule every time the SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived event is raised in the global.asax.

```
        if (validFrom.AddMinutes(halfSpan) < now && now < validTo)
        {
            var sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;

            e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal,
                e.SessionToken.Context,
                now,
                now.AddMinutes(5),
                e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
            e.ReissueCookie = true;
        }
```

Is there a better alternative to this method?

Answer (score 1):

Allen Brock, member of ThinkTecture, suggests we reissue the token if the session is still valid but more than halfway expired:

```
void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;

    var token = e.SessionToken;
    var duration = token.ValidTo.Subtract(token.ValidFrom);
    if (duration <= TimeSpan.Zero) return;

    var diff = token.ValidTo.Add(sam.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.MaxClockSkew).Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
    if (diff <= TimeSpan.Zero) return;

    var halfWay = duration.TotalMinutes / 2;
    var timeLeft = diff.TotalMinutes;
    if (timeLeft <= halfWay)
    {
        e.ReissueCookie = true;
        e.SessionToken =
            new SessionSecurityToken(
                token.ClaimsPrincipal,
                token.Context,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                DateTime.UtcNow.Add(duration))
            {
                IsPersistent = token.IsPersistent,
                IsReferenceMode = token.IsReferenceMode
            };
    }
}
```

If you approve, you need not write it yourself but can call it from `global.asax`:

```
public override void Init()
{
    PassiveModuleConfiguration.EnableSlidingSessionExpirations();
}
```

Source: http://brockallen.com/2013/02/17/sliding-sessions-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/

See also [Updating BootStrapContext with new SessionSecurityToken when using Sliding sessions in WIF with the SAM and Thinktecture IdentityModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984380/updating-bootstrapcontext-with-new-sessionsecuritytoken-when-using-sliding-sessi) for a problem with this: The BootStrapToken serialized to the current claims Identity remains the old one.